# Securing database records through Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, security, webforms, active-directory

**This question is an extension of my previous question. The prior question uses a similar approach but only uses active directory to populate cookies or session variables, which is useful only for simple things like populating a dropdown. Here I am extending that approach to populate a database table. The extended approach provides a technique for securing data in by creating joins in the database.**

Please comment on whether this is a "good" approach to securing database data through active directory.

**Scenario** Need to create an application for submitting & viewing accidents reports that will be used by 50 schools. The application needs a security mechanism to prevent employees from viewing data that is not in their school(s). Some employee's are to be assigned multiple schools. The IT department wants to create a security group for each school in Active Directory to control access to the application and it's data.

**Problem with Active Directory**
If not using Active Directory I would simply create a database table called UserSchool which would store the username and SchoolID. This would make it very simple to write queries that return data only pertinent to user's school. I would just have to add a join to the UserSchool table in my stored procedures.

**Possible Solultion** This solution is an attempt to gain the best of both worlds. Security will be managed through Active Directory. When an employee logs into the application the UserSchool table will be populated from Active Directory.

1. Create an OU in Active Directory called AccidentReportingSchools.
2. Create a security group for each school in the AccidentReportingSchools OU.
3. To each security group, add an attribute called SchoolID which corresponds to the primary key of a table called schools.
4. Create a table called UserSchools that will have an Username and SchoolId field.
5. When an employee logs into the application a delete statement such as DELETE FROM UserSchools WHERE UserName = @UserName.
6. After running the delete statement the table would be populated with their UserName and SchoolID which will be taken from the Active DIrectory security groups.

Comment: A quick search for *sql server row level security* turned out [Granting Row-Level Permissions in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669076%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - your plan seems very much overengineering the task. You do know you can grant permissions to AD security groups in SQL server?

Comment: It has been my understanding that in order to use Row-Level Permissions in SQL Server a license needs to be purchased for each user.

Comment: As far as I can see there's no SKU specific feature you'd need to implement this filtering. You'll need proper licensing in any case if you provide access to a MS SQL server database through a Web application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Active Directory to restrict access to data in webforms app (mainly through populating dropdowns)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758600/using-active-directory-to-restrict-access-to-data-in-webforms-app-mainly-throug)

Comment: Row Level Permissions in SQL Server is not an option for the following reasons:

Comment: Not sure what you mean by SKU specific feature. Typically an asp.net website uses a single username & password setup in web.config to connect to SQLServer. If the application is configured to pass the actual user credentials of the person using the web application to SQL Server not only would it require purchasing additional licences but it would also require giving individuals users direct access to the database. Allowing them to bypass the web application and write queries (including updates & deletes) directly against the database.

Comment: SKU specific features means features tied to for example SQL Server Enterprise Edition. Your statement about granting access to single users is plainly wrong: You can grant SQL Server permissions to AD groups containing your Users-per-School without explicitly naming any individual user in SQL Server itself.

Comment: Concering licensing: when using SQL Server as a Web application backend you'll always need to consider if you're better off licensing individual users accessing your database vs covering an anonymous group of users by purchasing a Web license. Could it be that you are living under the wrong impression that you'll only need to license 1 SQL user if configure this user in your web.config? You may be in for a big surprise.